# Can i use if to compare enum which contains parameter?

Tags: swift

For example, i delcare a enum with parameter like this

```
enum Foo {        
    case a(Int)
}
```

Then i can compare this enum with which clause like this

```
let f = Foo.a(10)

switch f {
case let .a(k):
    print(k)
}
```

---

#### My question is

Is it possible to compare this type of enum with if statement?

For example

```
if f == .a(_) {
    print("yes")
}
```

Comment: FYI This is called enumeration with associated values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. You have at least two options on top of the `switch` statement you already wrote.

- a. Use `Equatable`
- b. `if case`

#### Use `Equatable`

Make your `enum` `Equatable`, and use `==`. In your case you don't have to write any code other than:

```swift
enum Foo: Equatable {
    case a(Int)
}

if f == .a(10) {
    print("yes")
}
```

### Use `if case`

If you don't won't or can't easily make your type `Equatable` you can always use `if case`:

```swift
if case .a = f {
    print("yes")
}

if case .a(let x) = f, x == 10 {
    print("yes")
}
```

The second example is also handy if you want to capture the value to use it in the `if` branch, without necessarily inspecting it for the equatable check

```swift
if case .a(let x) = f {
    print(x)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution like this:

```
if case .a(let k) = f {
    print(k)
}
```

Comment: `or if case let .a(k) = f` Note that this is handy if you have multiple associated values and all of then are cconstants

Answer (score 0):

You can, if you make foo conform to Equatable

```
enum Foo: Equatable {
    case a(Int)
}
```

and then

```
// will print "no"
let f = Foo.a(10)
if f == .a(2) {
    print("yes")
} else {
    print("no")
}
```